# Is there any function to extract the indices generated from a cropbox

Tags: point-cloud-library

I've tried the pcl::cropbox and filtered a cloud based on the min and max x,y,z values given to the cropbox. I get the new cloud which contains only the point within the cropbox limits. Unfortunately I don't need a separate cloud, but need the indices which lie within the box. 
Note : I get the removed indices from the old cloud, but not the indices which lie inside cropbox.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("D:\ism_test.pcd", *cloud);


pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr bodyFiltered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter(true);
boxFilter.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(minX, minY, minZ, 1.0));
boxFilter.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(maxX, maxY, maxZ, 1.0));
boxFilter.setInputCloud(cloud);
boxFilter.FilterIndices(*bodyFiltered);
pcl::IndicesConstPtr removedIndices = boxFilter.getRemovedIndices();
pcl::IndicesConstPtr actualindices = boxFilter.getIndices();

//blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer filteredviewer("Filtered Viewer");
filteredviewer.showCloud(bodyFiltered);
```

Comment: Does the code you posted even compile? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry but posted only minimal code. Of course you need to add includes and libraries for it to build.

Answer (score 0):

pcl::CropBox inherited `filter (std::vector< int > &indices)`  so you should be able to call it to get the indices which lie within the box [see here for reference](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_filter_indices.html#abbbfa3686df4bdb6cd333a182180970d)

```cpp
pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter;
...
#
std::vector<int> indices_inside;
boxFilter.filter(indices_inside);
```

If you need the points out side the box, you can retrieve it with [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), for example

```cpp
std::vector<int> all_points(cloud.size());
std::iota(all_points.begin(), all_points.end()) // fill with 0, 1, 2, ..., n
std::vector<int> indices_inside = ...(from previous);
std::vector<int> indices_outside;

// process: indices_outside = all_points - indices_inside 
std::set_difference(all_points.begin(), all_points.end(),
                    indices_inside.begin(), indices_inside.end(), 
                    std::inserter(indices_outside, indices_outside.begin()));
```

Comment: Yes that is what I've done, using the differences. But it is a heavy procedure as segmentation of clouds occur.
Anyways this is the only solution found as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pcl::FilterIndices`'s `filter()` method and passing the `actualIndices` should to the trick, since `pcl::CropBox` inherits from `pcl::FilterIndices`. You can still get the indices of the points outside the box using `getRemovedIndices()`:

```cpp
pcl::IndicesPtr actualIndices(new std::vector<int>);
pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter(true);
boxFilter.FilterIndices(actualIndices);
// actualIndices now contains the inside-box indices
pcl::IndicesConstPtr removedIndices = boxFilter.getRemovedIndices();
// removedIndices now contains the outside-box indices
```

Note that in your original code, you called `boxFilter.FilterIndices()`, which is actually a constructor and not the filtering method. Call `boxFilter.filter()` instead.

Also, I have heard of PCL's crop box being buggy when using indices as opposed to a `PointCloud` object (at least in PCL 1.7, which is admittedly quite old), so if you still don't get the desired behavior this may be why. I haven't observed this bug myself.