# How do I label the pointcloud if I have the 3D boxes of the objects annotated?

Tags: python, c++, data-annotations, point-cloud-library

I am trying to annotate my point cloud data. I found a number of tools but could only access the demo version of 3D Point cloud tool by [Supervisely](https://supervise.ly/lidar-3d-cloud). Once the annotation is complete by drawing 3D boxes around the objects, the output annotation file is in the form of a JSON file. This contains, the class and global position, orientation and dimensions of the box. How do I use this file to assign labels to the points inside these 3D boxes. I want the output format in either .pcd file or .bin file. 
The output of the JSON file is as follows:

```
[{"id":36698,"name":"vel_1558647824006782.pcd","annotations":[{"className":"Car","geometryType":"cuboid","classId":957,"geometry":{"position":{"x":9.539855967959713,"y":18.342023271012913,"z":0.43944128482454614},"rotation":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0},"dimensions":{"x":5.691547052392309,"y":1.6625674002633986,"z":1.757779283656416}}},{"className":"ground","geometryType":"cuboid","classId":958,"geometry":{"position":{"x":28.890481890779242,"y":8.463823613489927,"z":-1.0314986175132965},"rotation":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0},"dimensions":{"x":96.34273328620523,"y":18.714553504372063,"z":1.0544185995045456}}}]}]
```

I thought of using a [crop_box filter](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html) by PCL. But is there any other way around it. It would also help if someone can point me to other point cloud annotation tools which could best help me solve the problem?

Comment: Too many questions. Could you clarify a bit? Do make sure that you don't fall into the trap of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a c++ script to read the json file and use PCL's [cropbox](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html) filter to solve the problem. The methodology used is as follows:

- 1) Read the json file using [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

```
std::ifstream ifs("somepath.json");
json j = json::parse(ifs);
```

- 2) Extract the "position" (centroid of cuboid), "orientation" of cuboid, "dimensions" of the cuboid and the "className" for each box. The code below shows a way to extract the position data into std::vector. (i is iterating over the number of boxes.)

```
std::vector<float> position {
    j[0]["annotations"][i]["geometry"]["position"]["x"].get<float>(),
    j[0]["annotations"][i]["geometry"]["position"]["y"].get<float>(),
    j[0]["annotations"][i]["geometry"]["position"]["z"].get<float>()};
```

- 3) Get the max and min (x,y,z) coordinate points of the vertices of the box. This goes as input to the cropbox filter. (Note: the x,y,z point does not have to relate to a single vertex. Xmin will be minimum x of all 8 vertices and Ymin will minium of all 8 vertices and so on.)
- 4) Use cropbox filter from PCL. This allows you to get indices of all the points inside the given box. Examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790828/remove-points-outside-defined-3d-box-inside-pcl-visualizer)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597119/is-there-any-function-to-extract-the-indices-generated-from-a-cropbox).
- 5) Depending upon the class of the box, assign different colors to the points at those indices of the point cloud.
- 6) Save the point cloud.

This would be  a generalized way of labeling every point of a point cloud from the an input json file which consists information of the position, dimension and orientation of the 3D cubes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it @Anirudh. There's a slight difference between the ideal output and your output. Your process labels excess points (outside the original box) since cropbox takes min and max of all 8 (as you duly noted in pt 3). I'm just mentioning for the future viewers.

Comment: @KunalTyagi  Thanks for pointing that out. I have seen in my annotations that some of the points outside the box is also being mis annotated. Could you please explain where I am going wrong and how I can fix it? Shouldn't the crop box filter return the indices that are only inside the box?

Comment: The cropbox filter is aligned to the cloud axis not the axis of the 3d label box given by your annotate tool. It might be a good feature to have in PCL though

Comment: I understand, but the orientation I am getting for the 3D box is with respect to the point cloud and that is what I am passing to the crop box filter. If possible can you please give some more details about the problem? I would appreciate the help!!!

Comment: Could you create a new question for this please? Comments aren't conducive to such discussions

Comment: @KunalTyagi I have asked a separate question. Would you be able to take a look?                                                                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163631/point-level-segmentation-from-box-annotation-of-point-cloud-using-crop-box-filte